# Matrix multiplication as combination of rotation and stretching

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm starting to look at some lectures on the SVD. The lectures start out by saying that in $$\mathbf{y}=A\mathbf{x}$$ the transformation representing $A$ is *only* doing rotation and stretching.

- The matrix for rotation is $$ \begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{bmatrix}$$
- The matrix for stretching is $$ \begin{bmatrix}\alpha&0\\0&\alpha\end{bmatrix}$$

In the past I've learnt that transformations can be rotations, reflections, scaling, shears, and flattenings. However the idea that any transformation can be decomposed into a rotation and a stretch is new to me. Is there a clear and/or intuitive way of explaining this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One major theme in the study of matrix algebra is that of [matrix decompositions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_decomposition). The idea is to take a matrix $A$ (either arbitrary or satisfying some reasonable conditions) and decompose it as the product of two or three matrices of a simpler form. For example, the so-called **QR decomposition** writes an arbitrary matrix $A$ as

$$A = QR$$

Where $Q$ is orthogonal (a composition of rotations + reflections) and $R$ is upper-triangular. In two-dimensions, $Q$ is either rotation or reflection.

In the subject of SVD, an important matrix decomposition is the aptly-named **singular value decomposition**. This writes an arbitrary matrix $A$ in the form

$$A = UDV^{H}$$

where $D$ is a nonnegative, diagonal matrix whose entries are called the *singular values*, $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal (unitary in the complex case), and $V^{H}$ is the transpose of $V$ (or conjugate-transpose if complex entries are allowed). A diagonal matrix can be thought of as stretching a basis by the corresponding singular values, and an orthogonal matrix is a rotation or reflection. Thus, this decomposition sees $A$ as a composition of a sort of rotation (transposed), a stretching, and finally another rotation.

You can read more about the singular value decomposition [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition).

Comment: Thanks. My question was supposed to be independent of the SVD (but within the context), in that the lecture starts off without mentioning the SVD and claims that every matrix transformation is a combination of rotation and scaling. Reading your answer and looking over the lecture material again, I'm beginning to feel that maybe _this is what the SVD shows_, that the lecturer's statement was saying what the SVD gives you, rather than giving a premise from which the SVD follows. Is that a fair summary -- that the SVD shows that the decomposition is valid?

Comment: I might be mistaken here (I'm not too knowledgeable about this area), but I think that is correct. SVD is a powerful tool and proving that it exists is tantamount to showing that one's matrix can be decomposed into rotations, scalings, and rotations (in that order).